# Knex.js won't connect to postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database using Knex.js, but I just can't get a connection to happen. The only exception I'm seeing is:

> Error KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?

I built this simple test script to make sure it wasn't part of our program:

```html
const knex = require("knex")({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host : 'localhost',
        port: 5432,
        database: 'postgres',
        user: 'postgres',
        password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
        afterCreate: (conn, done) => {
            console.log("Pool created");
            done(false, conn);
        }
    },
    debug: true,
    acquireConnectionTimeout: 2000
});

console.log("A")

const a = knex.raw('select 1+1 as result').then(result => console.log("A Success", result)).catch(err => console.log("A Error", err));

console.log("B")

const b = knex.select("thing").from("testdata").then(data => console.log("B Success", data)).catch(err => console.log("B Error", err));

console.log("C")

const c = knex.transaction(trx => {
    trx.select("thing").from("testdata")
        .then(data => {
            console.log("C Success", data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("C Error", err);
        });
})
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("C Error", err);
    });

console.log("waiting on query")
// Promise.all([a, b, c]).then(() => {
//     console.log("Destroying")
//     knex.destroy()
// })
```

Which is producing the following output

```
A
B
C
waiting on query
A Error KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
    at Client_PG.acquireConnection (E:\DEV\work\niba-backend\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:347:26)
    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:58:5)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:520:9)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:494:7) {
  sql: 'select 1+1 as result',
  bindings: undefined
}
B Error KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
    at Client_PG.acquireConnection (E:\DEV\work\niba-backend\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:347:26) {
  sql: undefined,
  bindings: undefined
}
C Error KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
    at Client_PG.acquireConnection (E:\DEV\work\niba-backend\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:347:26)
    at async Transaction.acquireConnection (E:\DEV\work\niba-backend\node_modules\knex\lib\transaction.js:213:28)
```

It's never calling the afterCreate method. I have tried it against both our dev database using settings that work for everyone else, and a locally running postgres installation with every combination of settings I could come up with. I even passed this off to another member of the team and it worked fine, so there's something up in my machine, but I have no idea what could be blocking it. I'm not seeing any connection attempts in the postgres logs, and I can't seem to get any better error messages to work off of.

If anyone could come up with things I can try, or ways to get more information out of Knex I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You could try removing `afterCreate` completely and make sure that your local machine postgres is running. Also in your transaction handler you should return a Promise from the handler to trigger implicit commit / rollback. Basically everything seems to point to a direction that postgres has been configured in a way that it is not accepting TCP connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I traced the issue down to the verion of the 'pg' package we were using. Was using 7.18 and when I upgraded to the latest version (8.4) it started connecting. No idea why the 7.x version wasn't working.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR POSTING THIS. :)  We had code that stopped working and changing the version of pg worked. :)